# ListView Items does not register click after ListView is scrolled down and up

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` with a with a Custom Adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter`, My ListView has `5` different types of Items that it can hold, That's why I am using an `ArrayAdapter` well the issue is fairy odd to me, I am not sure how to debug this. I will post the video.

[image]

as you can see I'm clicking my `Checkbox` and `Modal` Items without any issue at the start but as soon as I scroll down and back up they don't click anymore! This is a really weird bug I'm facing. Here is how I do my adapter.

This is my adapter class code. It's fairly compact.

```
public class SettingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Setting> {
    private List<Setting> settings;

    public SettingAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
        setSettings(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public SettingAdapter(Context context, List<Setting> settings) {
        super(context, 0);
        setSettings(settings);
    }

    public void setSettings(List<Setting> settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
        clear();
        addAll(settings);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Setting getItem(int i) {
        return settings.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position)).getView(getContext());
    }
}
```

I have an `abstract` class called `Setting` my `ListView` Items will extend that class and implement `getView()` and such.

Here is an example.

```
public class Summary extends Setting {
    private View view;

    public Summary(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public int getType() {
        return SettingType.SUMMARY;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(Context context) {
        if(view == null) {
            view = //Load the view here
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

I'm also saving my `View` reference for later, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here can anyone guide me towards how to debug this or fix this? Have spent over 10 hours still no success.

Comment: How you create the view?
because every time the view show in list view the method  *getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)* will be invoked, so be sure the state of view will not be change while you scrolling.  or try to use recyclerview it's much better.

Comment: @MohamdAli why will it be invoked? I am saving the view as global variable and then checking if its null if it is then create a view, if not return the old view.

Comment: Try to debug the the method while you scrolling, it will invoked every time the view appear in the screen.
read this article it's useful http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Did you even look at my code?

Comment: sure, OK let me check it on my machine:D

Comment: I'm caching the view, It should not create the view if it is already created.Because I am saving it in global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, try to not Caching the view, just recreate it on Setting.getView(Context context) and save the state of view and return it.

I Create 4 different items and work with me.

If you want to cache view i really recommended [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: I do my best ^_^

Comment: I am sorry, i did it in small project here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qbj_BcBNLAVvzeruNFLys5Mvkm6olJND and its work with me, you can vote down my answer ^_^